# Where to add shared view files in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and I want to use shared files in my project. I have searched the web about this, and I got some results as follow:

For Rails 3

```
app/views/shared
```

For Rails 4

```
app/views/application
```

but there was nothing for Rails 5.

I am talking about the standard; is there any specific location to add common view files in Rails 5, just as we do in other frameworks? Like in Laravel there is a layout folder?

Comment: The name for shared partials folder is not a standard, just a matter of taste / coding style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the people telling you that there is no "standard location" for common view files are correct.  However, if you want to ask Rails where it would go looking for a partial file if you attempted to render one on the view, just take any view file you have and render a partial you know doesn't exist.

If you have, say, a `UsersController` with a view structure that looks something like `app/view/users`, and you add the following on any view there:

```
<%= render 'foo' %>
```

You'll likely get an error that says something like:

```
Missing partial users/_foo, application/_foo
```

That means that whenever you attempt to render a partial by just it's name without any path information, Rails will look for it

- first under the view directory for the current controller, in this case `users`
- then under the `application` directory

So, I guess then you could say that the "default location" in Rails for common view files is under the `application` directory.

It's possible to add to this in order to create your app's own "standard location" for common view files by overriding the [`ActionView::ViewPaths.local_prefixes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-0/actionview/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb#L27) private class method that gets mixed in to every controller in Rails:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def self.local_prefixes
    ['shared', controller_path]
  end
  private_class_method :local_prefixes
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def self.local_prefixes
    [controller_path]
  end
  private_class_method :local_prefixes
end
```

Now, your error will say something like:

```
Missing partial users/_foo, shared/_foo, application/_foo
```

which shows that Rails will check the `shared` directory for partials as well before it goes looking in the `application` directory.

Note that this method override should happen in *both* the controllers, otherwise the `local_prefixes` in `UsersController` get inherited from `ApplicationController` and you end up with duplicated lookup paths that look like:

```
shared/_foo, users/_foo, shared/_foo, application/_foo
```

If all this is too much effort/too weird, as other people have pointed out, you can always just specify your shared partial directory manually when you render a partial:

```
<%= render 'shared/foo' %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create new directory in `app/views` directory and add your shared file in that directory.
Ex:

```
app/views/shared # Contains all shared/partial pages
```

Now create your partial page in `app/views/shared` directory
like: `app/views/shared/_my_shared_view.html.erb`

Now if you want use this shared view in any view just add the below code.

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/my_shared_view' %>
```

That's it. Hope this will help you.

Comment: the standard you are using is of Rails 3, i am using Rails 5, it doesn't mean this doesn't work in Rails 5, but it's not the correct way

Comment: So, exactly what kind of shared template you want to load?

Comment: i am talking about the standard, means is there any specific location to add common view files in Rails 5, just as we do in other frameworks, like in Laravel there is a layout folder,

Comment: Yes, In `rails` there is also a `layouts` in `app/views/layouts` from where the all pages are render as default view by ``app/views/layouts/application.html.erb``

Comment: you can create your custom shared view and put it into `app/views/layouts` and use it. like: `app/views/layouts/myview.html.erb`

Comment: @Insomania there is no standard for how you organize shared partials. As they are shared, most developers put them in `shared`, but you can do the same in a `common` folder, it doesn't change anything. The `layout` folder is for the actual page layout...